# How could I create a popup form when clicking a button?

Tags: popup

I would like to create a popup form which will ask a user if he/she agrees with the terms and condition and has a post and cancel button. How could I create one? Could you give me an example. Thank you.

Comment: We're going to need a *lot* more details than that. For starters, what language/technology are you trying to do this in? Try to fill in all 5 tag slots.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Leave tizag.com?")
    if (answer){
        alert("Bye bye!")
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
    else{
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
    }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="confirmation()" value="Leave Tizag.com">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Taken from TizTag...or you could use jQuery Dialog :)

Comment: Aren't "Do you really want to leave this fantastic, wonderful, awesome website?" messages annoying? Yeah, I thought so too.